# How to set values for all rows from group for certain criteria in Tableau

Tags: calculated-columns, tableau-api

I need to create one Calculated Field "IsProductPresent" (see last column). I have shown here as part of data so that we can compare if our results are right or wrong.

This is basically retail store data - Group of transactions is called Basket (Represented by BasketId) and each item in the basket is one row here (BasketItemNbr). Goal is to find if certain product is present in the basket. If it is present then we should mark "IsProductPresent" to 1 else 0.

What is the criteria for deciding the product?
Criteria is BSKReqID = 308 & ProductBarocde = '0049000000443' , '0049000000450'.

So if there is even one transaction in Basket which satisfies above criteria then IsProductPresent should give me 1  for all the transactions of that basket else 0.

please share  emailid so that I can share Sample Data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LOD calculations for this. One example:

```
{ FIXED [BasketId] : MAX(IIF([BSKReqID] = 308 AND ([ProductBarcode] = '0049000000443' OR [ProductBarcode] = '0049000000450'), 1, 0)) }
```

I'll break that down.

```
IIF([BSKReqID] = 308 AND ([ProductBarcode] = '0049000000443' OR [ProductBarcode] = '0049000000450'), 1, 0)
```

That's an inline if statement. It says "If the BSKReqID is 308 and the barcode is one of these barcodes, then return 1. Otherwise, return 0."

Then we aggregate that with `MAX()`. Since the inline if statement can only return a 1 or a 0, `MAX()` will necessarily return one of those values - 1 if the item is present, 0 if it's not.

```
{ FIXED [BasketId] : ... }
```

That says that we're only going to use BasketId in our aggregation. That way, BasketItemNumber will not be included in the `MAX()` aggregation, and we will calculate that 0 or 1 for the entire Basket rather than for the BasketLineNumber.

Comment: This answer needs to be accepted, it's an excellent answer. @rb004